# np.load(), returns the wrong values from a npy file

Tags: numpy

I use a PC to do simulations and save the results as .npy file using

```
np.save('status_matrix2',status_mat)
```

I used to load these files on my laptop and there were no problems until now, there is only one file which is returning correct values when I load it with the PC, but when I transfer and load it on my laptop I get big negative integer numbers and this error `runtimewarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars`

there is no huge numbers in the matrix, I use `np.load` to load the file.

Comment: I'd check the versions, pyrhon and numpy.   And maybe retry the transfer.

Comment: @hpailj  I have other npy files from the same simulation, I read then on my laptop without a problem. all versions inside the work PC is the same on my laptop

Comment: Then my best guess is that the problem file was corrupted in some way in the transfer.

Comment: @hpailj  you are right the file was corrupted, I transferred the file with flash USB. I did it 3 times and it only affected that file and not others, finally, I transferred it by internet and it was ok. there were no viruses around